# Rotate image and adjust space

Tags: css, image, rotation, overlap, adjustment

I want to rotate a picture (90 degrees) that is between two boxes. The problem is that the picture overlaps the two boxes in this case.

### Example 1: [Wrong formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3CBL.png)

CSS:

```
.box{
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='box'>Top</div>
    <img style='transform: rotate(90deg);' src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/10/20/56/feather-3010848_960_720.jpg' width='200px'>
<div class='box'>Bottom</div>
```

### Example 2: [Desired formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS8lI.png)

There is a solution, but I can not use it because "image-orientation" is not recognized by all browsers (especially mobile devices):

```
<div class='box'>Top</div>
    <img style='image-orientation: 90deg;' src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/10/20/56/feather-3010848_960_720.jpg' width='200px'>
<div class='box'>Bottom</div>
```

Is there any other solution that a rotated image does not overlap other elements? Or is there any alternative for image-orientation that works with all browsers?

Comment: what are you tring to do ?

Comment: The first thing you should do is change the id into a class. Then, use a square image.

Comment: I have different pictures, not just square pictures. Note, what I wrote above is a very reduced example. (By clicking a button, users should be able to rotate an image by 90 degrees.) This image is in a certain area, which should automatically adapt to the rotated image so that the image does not overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to keep the image in a relative space such as a restricted width then I would suggest the following which adds a div tag around the image, uses the before pseudo selector to create an aspect ratio based off of the boxes max with of 1:1 width & height, then absolute positioning the image within that to rotate around a center access point. See code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.box{
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.box--image {     
    position:relative;    
    max-width:200px; 
    outline:solid 1px red;
}

.box--image:before {
    content:"";
    display:block; 
    padding-top:100%;
}

.box--image img {    
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;          
    top:50%;
    transform:rotate(90deg) translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform-origin:top left;
    width:200px;
}
```

```
<div class="box">Top</div>
    <div class="box--image"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/10/20/56/feather-3010848_960_720.jpg" /></div>
<div class="box">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works as I imagined. However, that's a lot of CSS code for a simple task (rotate an image by 90deg). Or? I wish there was a simple alternative for "image-orientation".